# AND OR not working correctly in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to exclude the following code but it keeps returning ones that shouldn't be there or excludes too many when I use 'and'. What am I doing wrong?

```
select idnum
,svcdat
,swpanum
,svccod
,modcod
from test1
where swpanum not in (1,16,19)
or (svccod <> 't587' or modcod not in ('u4','u5')
and svccod <> 'w447' or modcod <> 'x'
and svccod <> 'h322' or modocd <> 'kh')
```

Comment: try this where swpanum not in (1,16,19)
or (svccod <> 't587' or modcod not in ('u4','u5')
and (svccod <> 'w447' or modcod <> 'x')
and (svccod <> 'h322' or modocd <> 'kh'))

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis are important. I suspect you want:

```sql
SELECT idnum,
       svcdat,
       swpanum,
       svccod,
       modcod
FROM dbo.test1
WHERE swpanum NOT IN (1,16,19)
   OR ((svccod <> 't587' OR modcod NOT IN ('u4','u5'))
  AND  (svccod <> 'w447' OR modcod <> 'x')
  AND  (svccod <> 'h322' OR modocd <> 'kh'));
```

Comment: It is still returning swpa 1 and 16

Comment: Perhaps the first `OR` should be an `AND`; of course we have no sample data, so we have no way of actually knowing this, and why the above was a suspicion.

Comment: You will receive rows where swpanum = 1 or swpanum = 16 if ANY of the clauses following the first OR are True.   As noted by @Larnu, perhaps the first OR should be an AND.